# Find the probability that Mr A misses first train but catches the second train

Tags: probability

. . The time it takes him to reach the station varies uniformly between 15 to 20 minutes. From stations there are 2 trains one at 9:20 and other at 9:27

Basically somehow I managed to reduce the question to the following

Let p be number of integral solutions to the given equation

$$ x + y + z = 14 $$
$$ 0<x<11 ,   0<y<6,   0<z<8 $$
      Probability = $p\over 50$

But the answer didn't match

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: And what is the value of $p$ you have found?

Comment: Wasn't it $\frac p{200}$?

Comment: Does this picture give you any ideas? https://i.imgur.com/vUZ7swx.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer refers to the original version of the question. Now the question does not make sense anymore.)

This has nothing to do with integers. A's departure time $d$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,10]$, and his walking time $w$ is uniformly distributed in $[15,20]$. It follows that the point $(d,w)$ is uniformly (with respect to euclidean measure) distributed in the rectangle $R:=[0,10]\times[15,20]$ of area $50$. We are asked to determine the probability that the total time $t:=d+w$ is lying in the interval $[20,27]$. This probability is given by $$p={{\rm area}(A)\over50}\ ,$$ whereby the shape $A$ is defined by
$$A:=\{(d,w)\in R\,|\, 20\leq d+w\leq27\}\ .$$
Draw a figure and determine ${\rm area}(A)$ using elementary geometry.